# Get-RenderingParameter is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell-extensions, presentation

I'm writing a script to exchange a rendering component with a new rendering component, but it should keep all of the same rendering parameters. I followed the documentation to use Get-RenderingParamater to pass the dictionary to the new component, but I'm getting that it is not recognized as a cmdlet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Emily and welcome to the Sitecore Stack Exchange. Can you please provide additional details about which version of Sitecore and SPE you are using? I imagine you will need to have installed Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 5.1 for this feature to work.

Comment: same issue, if someone get answer ?

Comment: @JayantVaishnav read the comment above about it requiring a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added in SPE 5.1. If you install that version or newer the command should be available.

Read more about it in the pull request here https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/pull/1074